# Is there a way to use std::condition_variable::wait(lock, pred) without a lambda?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, condition-variable

I found this code online explaining how to use a `std::condition_variable` to solve the Producer-Consumer Problem: [Producer-Consumer Problem Using Condition Variable in C++](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/producer-consumer-problem-using-condition-variable-in-c-6c4d96efcbbc)

```cpp
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variale
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

std::mutex g_mutex;
std::condition_variable g_cv;

bool g_ready = false;
int g_data = 0;

int produceData() {
  int randomNumber = rand() % 1000;
  std::cout << "produce data: " << randomNumber << "\n";
  return randomNumber;
}

void consumeData(int data) { std::cout << "receive data: " << data << "\n"; }

void consumer() {
  int data = 0;
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(g_mutex);
    g_cv.wait(ul, []() { return g_ready; });
    consumeData(g_data);
    g_ready = false;
    ul.unlock();
    g_cv.notify_one();
  }
}

void producer() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(g_mutex);
    g_data = produceData();
    g_ready = true;
    ul.unlock();
    g_cv.notify_one();
    ul.lock();
    g_cv.wait(ul, []() { return g_ready == false; });
  }
}

void consumerThread(int n) { consumer(); }

void producerThread(int n) { producer(); }

int main() {
  int times = 100;
  std::thread t1(consumerThread, times);
  std::thread t2(producerThread, times);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

My code works, but my coding standard says I'm not allowed to use lambdas.
How can I use this code without using lambdas in `wait()`?

I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

1. use a normal `bool`

```cpp
wait(g_ready)
```

Comment: Just pass some other callable, such as a function pointer or an object with a defined and compatible `operator()`.  Or improve your coding standards.

Comment: Yes you can use a free function too.

Comment: I agree get your coding standards upgraded. Unless you are in an environment where you have to interface with "C" code that needs function pointers (then lambdas with captures might be a challenge). If you are not on embedded system pass this on to whoever is responsible for your coding standards : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: What is the justification for disallowing lambdas?  That is absolutely the first question I would ask.

Comment: "but for coding standards I'm not allowed to use lambdas" - What a stupid rule. You should challenge that.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote all of those "what a stupid rule!" comments about a thousand times each. What a stupid rule! Is it because somebody who's above you in the corporate food chain doesn't quite understand what lambdas actually are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, disallowing lambdas is a dubious decision for a coding standard. Regardless, lambdas are just convenience syntax for creating types with a call operator, which you could do by hand.

### Solution with callable struct

The lambda expression:

```cpp
[]() { return g_ready; }
```

roughly translates into

```cpp
struct g_ready_checker {
    bool operator()() const noexcept {
        return g_ready;
    }
};
```

You could then do the following:

```cpp
g_cv.wait(ul, g_ready_checker{});
```

We can also turn `g_ready_checker` into a class template with a `<bool DesiredValue>` parameter, or we could store the value `g_ready` is meant to have as a class member.

### Solution with free function

Or alternatively, since this lambda isn't capturing anything, you could also write a free function, possibly as a template:

```cpp
template <bool DesiredValue>
bool is_g_ready() {
    return g_ready == DesiredValue;
}

/* ... */
g_cv.wait(ul, &is_g_ready<true>);
/* ... */
g_cv.wait(ul, &is_g_ready<false>);
```

Here, we provide `wait` with a predicate which is a function pointer. Note that the `Predicate` template parameter of [`std::condition_variable_wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) is not restricted to lambdas, it accepts anything callable which returns something convertible `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to avoid a lambda.

Given that `std::condition_variable::wait` offers both these overloads:

```cpp
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock );

template< class Predicate >
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate stop_waiting );
```

If you have some `std::condition_variable cv`, then calling `cv.wait(lock, stop_waiting);`
is equivalent to:

```cpp
while (!stop_waiting()) {
    cv.wait(lock);
}
```

So just don't provide the second argument `stop_waiting` (where one might provide a lambda) and instead call `wait(lock)` and check your condition manually in a loop. Changing `g_cv.wait(ul, []() { return g_ready; });` to not use a lambda would simply look like this:

```cpp
while(!g_ready) {
    g_cv.wait(ul);
}
```

[refer to the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)